# How to get from Hong Kong airport to Shenzhen while obtaining a 5-day visa at the border and if possible avoiding stairs?

Tags: airports, transportation, hong-kong, shenzhen

How to get from Hong Kong airport (HKG) to Shenzhen while obtaining a 5-day visa ("Shenzhen Special Economic Zone Tourism Visa") at the border as a French citizen, and if possible avoiding stairs?

Comment: I can't speak to accessibility with any authority, but there is a bus from the airport to Hung Hom station, from where you can get a train to the Lo Wu crossing where you can get this visa. That's the easiest (fewest connections) public transport connection (that I know of) rather than the quickest.

Comment: See for example: https://www.hongdaservice.com/blog/updated-5day-shenzhen-visa-on-arrival-to-china . If you have accessibility problems, it may  be a good idea to get a Visa upfront. This may include a lot of waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Get a VISA up front, there are plenty of agents who can help if you do not want to do it yourself.

Then take the train from the Station next to the Sheraton Towers on Kowloon side, I dont know the station name unfortunately but they have accessibility entrances.

Once you reach the border you go to the VISA part and realize your visa and then pass immigrations and voila, you are in Shenzhen.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from taking a cab straight from Hong Kong airport to Lo Wu station, you can use the train as follows:

1. Take the airport express train at Hong Kong airport (HKG)
2. Change at Tsing Yi station to the Tung Chung Line
3. Change at Nam Cheong to take the West Rail Line
4. Change at Hung Hom to take the East Rail line
5. Stop at Lo Wu station
6. At Lo Wu: Go to the first floor (aka second floor from an American standpoint) to get the visa. Then go on the basement floor to clear the immigration. Important: don't go to the basement without visa, otherwise you'll have to take stairs to go from the basement floor to the ground floor.
7. You're now in Shenzhen. You can get a taxi or a train right at the exit of the station.

None of the steps require going through stairs: they all have escalators and I'm quite sure they all have elevators as well.